# how to cross-domain jquery ajax responce using get method?

Tags: jquery, jsonp

How to make an asynchronous cross-domain request(GET) to a json-file using jQuery or something with node.js?
I have my api and I just need to make a request to the file

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "https://api.flightstats.com/flex/airports/rest/v1/json/active?appId=3a311b8b&appKey=5d67203e8afab7fe8d01e0debf177171",
    processData: true,
    data: {},
    dataType: "json"

});
```

Result

```
XMLHttpRequest
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.flightstats.com/flex/airports/rest/v1/json/active?appId=3a311b8b&appKey=5d67203e8afab7fe8d01e0debf177171. Origin https://developer.flightstats.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

or

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "https://api.flightstats.com/flex/airports/rest/v1/json/active?appId=3a311b8b&appKey=5d67203e8afab7fe8d01e0debf177171?callback?",
    processData: true,
    data: {},
    dataType: "jsonp"        
});
```

Result

```
undefined
```

Comment: [Reading the docs](https://developer.flightstats.com/api-docs/how_to), if you try to use `JSONP`, you should change `json` to `jsonp` in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

your url callback function missing `=`. here is the correct url. then try it out.

1. Make sure that you'are not getting any 404 erros in console.
2. Check for console for any other erros.

   ```
   $.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
       url: "https://api.flightstats.com/flex/airports/rest/v1/json/active?appId=3a311b8b&appKey=5d67203e8afab7fe8d01e0debf177171?callback=?",
       processData: true,
       data: {},
       dataType: "jsonp",
       success:function(data){//do some thing with data},
       error:function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){//do with ajax errors}
   });
   ```

Comment: <code>$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "https://api.flightstats.com/flex/airports/rest/v1/json/active?appId=3a311b8b&appKey=5d67203e8afab7fe8d01e0debf177171?callback=?",
    processData: true,
    data: {},
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success:function(data){console.log(data);},
    error:function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){console.log(thrownError);}
});
undefined
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : </code>

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   url: "https://api.flightstats.com/flex/airports/rest/v1/json/active?appId=3a311b8b&appKey=5d67203e8afab7fe8d01e0debf177171?callback=?",
   dataType: "jsonp",
   success:function(data){
       console.log(data);
   }      
});
```

Comment: result  undefined
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : From chrome console